# Número de dígitos en números binarios

Tags: javascript

Intento desarrollar una calculadora ip pero la cosa se complica cuando convierto los octetos a binario pues al hacerlo necesito que sean 8 dígitos.

```
Decimal 12 = Binario 1100  ---> Mal
```

```
Decimal 12 = Binario 00001100.  ----> Bien
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo lograr esto?

---

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
var ceros '00000000';
var bin = (12).toString(2);
var binario = ceros.substr(bin.length) + bin;
console.log(binario);
```

Comment: Necesitaría ver el código de cómo lo haces para darte una mejor solución. Así solo podría decirte que lo pases a string y rellenes los huecos con 0 por delante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Binarios**

Para el caso donde siempre se agregan ceros a la izquierda hasta llevar a 8 dígitos, con enteros positivos menores a 256.

```js
var decimal = 12, 
    binario = ('0000000' + decimal.toString(2)).substr(-8);
    
console.log(binario);  // => 00001100
```

Se concatenan 7 ceros con el número, y con [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substr) se toman los últimos 8 caracteres.

---

**Generalizando para cualquier número**

Como función para cualquier número, con cualquier N de dígitos y en cualquier base (2 a 36):

```js
function rellenarCeros(numero, digitos, base = 10){
    let num = Math.abs(numero).toString(base),
        len = num.split('.',1)[0].length,
        signo = numero<0?'-':'';
    
    return signo + '0'.repeat(Math.max(0,digitos-len)) + num;
}


//Pruebas
console.log( rellenarCeros(  4321, 6   ) ); // => 004321
console.log( rellenarCeros( 43.21, 6   ) ); // => 000043.21
console.log( rellenarCeros( -4321, 6   ) ); // => -004321
console.log( rellenarCeros(  4321, 2   ) ); // => 4321
console.log( rellenarCeros(   106, 8, 2) ); // => 01101010
console.log( rellenarCeros(  1023, 8, 2) ); // => 1111111111
```

- Para que funcione en IE, se debe agregar el [método Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/repeat#Polyfill) de `String.prototype.repeat()`

Comment: @Marcos Claro, buen comentario. Agregado ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar el método [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart) para rellenar de ceros a la izquierda.

```js
const decimal = 12;
const binary = (decimal).toString(2).padStart(8, 0);

console.log(binary);
```

> Polyfill para el uso del método `padStart`: [Enlace](https://github.com/KhaledElAnsari/String.prototype.padStart)